# MATLAB: Matrix with binary info (1 and 0) and image command show nothing

Tags: matlab

After processing an input I finally have a matrix of N x M x L representing a volume. The values on that matrix are only 0 or 1. When I try to display a "slice" from this volume using image like this:

```
image(volume(:,:,80))
```

the displayed figure is all blue. Now if I use imagesc, the image is displayed ok (in blue and red tones). I think this is related to colormap but can't really figure out how to display the images with the image command.
My final goal is to display 3 or 4 slices in one 3d plot, somthing similar to what is shown here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html#f5-4457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your problem is related to colormap. Try

```
image(volume(:,:,80))
colorbar
```

You will see that your current colormap ranges from 0 to 64. If you use this command instead:

```
image(volume(:,:,80),'CDataMapping','scaled')
colorbar
```

you should get the image you want, and your colormap is now scaled to the range of your data (of course, you don't need to show the `colorbar` to get the right scaling, I just added it to make things more clear).